# In Scala, can I override Java Calendar's toString and have a constructor with a TimeZone?

Tags: scala, constructor, calendar, tostring

I have Java Calendar objects in my Scala code, because I interface with Java code that expects a Calendar.  Maybe that is a problem in itself.  But if it isn't, in the debugger I want `toString` to give me something immediately understandable (e.g., `2015-02-25T22:00:00Z` rather than the object format gibberish that comes by default.  I tried `class Cal extends GregorianCalendar` but then when I tried to make a `Cal(tz: TimeZone)` constructor I had problems.  What should I do?  Or should I just use Joda-Time?

Comment: Just use Joda Time. Or Java 8's java.time package. Both are *much* nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely do want to use a different API with better/safer features, but you could mix in a trait on a given instance of Calendar to override some behavior:

```
  trait SpecialPrint { self: Calendar =>    
    override def toString(): String = self.toInstant().toString + ", " + self.getTimeZone.getDisplayName
  }

  val c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault) with SpecialPrint

  def operation(c: Calendar) {
    println(c)
  }

  operation(c) // prints 2015-02-25T22:46:42.097Z, Eastern Standard Time
```

The calendar I used already had a `TimeZone` constructor, so I figured that would work for you.

Above i used a typed self reference (`self: Calendar =>`) to make a self reference of the right type to use in the `toString` call.

If you try to use this mixin on a class that doesn't extend `Calendar` it will fail, i.e. this code wont compile:

```
  class Other()
  val s = new Other() with SpecialPrint // illegal inheritance
```